# Align an image in the center of a button in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image that I've placed inside a button, and the issue is in Firefox, the image is aligned properly but in IE the image is moving to the right corner of the button.

I tried many ways to align it to center but nothing worked. I am creating the button and the image dynamically, and I had reduced the width and height of the image - that's the reason it is improperly aligned in IE, but I don't want to change the height and width for the image and button

Here's the code I'm using now:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.setAttribute("type","button");
button.setAttribute("id","primaryDelTel"+nameCode+telephoneCount);
button.setAttribute("class","greybutton");
button.setAttribute("style","width:20px;height:20px;");
var delButton = document.createElement("img");
delButton.setAttribute("src","/theme/images/deleteButton.png");
delButton.setAttribute("height","10");
delButton.setAttribute("width","9");
button.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Hi can you provide maybe a jsfiddle? of what you are currently doing? or sample screenshots of what is currently occurring. Thanks

Comment: how to upload a screen shot in this?

Comment: use `Prnt Scr` (Paste into mspaint) upload on your favorite image host and use this code `![message](image url)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.setAttribute("type","button");
button.setAttribute("id","primaryDelTel" + nameCode + telephoneCount);
button.setAttribute("class","greybutton");
button.setAttribute("style","width:20px; height:20px; padding:0; position:relative;");
document.body.appendChild(button);

var delButton = document.createElement("img");
delButton.setAttribute("src","/theme/images/deleteButton.png");
delButton.setAttribute("height","10");
delButton.setAttribute("width","10");
delButton.setAttribute("style","position:absolute; top:3px; left:3px;");
button.appendChild(delButton);
```

Here is in example on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tf8K3/1/